# Autofac: Is there any way to get an existing LifetimeScope from the Container so I can avoid passing its reference around?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have just started using Autofac in a WPF project. I have registered several types so that they use InstancePerLifetimeScope.

So, for example:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyType>()
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
IContainer container = builder.Build();
```

Now, I want to create a lifetimeScope that `MyType` can be resolved into.

So, I do this as follows inside one of my ViewModels:

```
        var lts = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
        lts.Resolve<MyType>();
```

All is good so far.

But I need to resolve `MyType` from within other ViewModels while keeping it in the SAME LifeTimeScope. The only way I can see to do this is to pass the `lts` reference around into the other ViewModels so I can do the resolution there.

Is there any way I can get / retrieve the scope referenced by `lts` from the container so I can avoid having to pass it around to other ViewModels?

So, in pseudo code: `container.GetScope["xxx"].Resolve<MyType>();`.

Or, perhaps Autofac already has an approach to deal with this type of scenario?

Comment: This doesn’t really make sense. You should resolve your root Types and the DI container will do the job of managing lifetime instances and dependency graph.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius thank you for your reply. I am sorry to say that I don't see what you mean. The only thing I can think you mean is to 1) Create the new lifetimescope, 2) Resolve from the container and not the scope. But doing this puts the resolved object in the 'root' scope and not the newly created scope. I confirmed this by doing `var lts = container.BeginLifeTimeScope(); obj1 = container.Resolve<MyType>(); obj2 = lts.Resolve<MyType>() ; var same = object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)`. The same variable returns false meaning the 2 objects are in different scopes.

Comment: So, it is my belief that to get an object to exist in a certain scope you have to resolve using a reference to that scope. So, lts.Resolve<MyType>() puts MyType in the lts scope, and container.Reolve<MyType>() puts MyType in the root scope.

Comment: So, going back to my original problem, if I want to get the same instances from the `lts` scope in other ViewModels then I am going to have to pass `lts` to them in order to resolve.

Comment: Likelihood is that you are trying to solve XY problem here so better update your question as to why exactly this problem arises for you.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I will edit my original question to try and make my scenario more understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Parent lifetime scopes, including the container, do not track or keep references to created lifetime scopes. This means [if you create a lifetime scope, it's up to you to track it and to ensure it gets properly disposed](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#child-scopes-are-not-automatically-disposed). If you need a way to locate a scope that was created, it's up to you to build that mechanism. In other app types the integration library helps with that - for example, in ASP.NET apps the request lifetime is tracked with the current request context. There is no specific integration library for WPF applications provided by the Autofac team at this time so it'd be up to you to find such a thing or create some mechanism that works for you. There is no guidance or specific recommendations about how to accomplish that because how it gets tracked, when things get disposed or created, etc. is going to be very application specific.